# JavaScript:Cannot manipulate array produced with string.match

Tags: javascript, arrays, match, splice

I have produced an array using:

```
var arr = [];
arr = string.match(regex here);
```

The array consists of words which I need to filter, so I am trying to use .splice to remove unwanted instances of the same word using:

```
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (arr[i] === 'jim') {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

The for loop doesn't recognize any instances of 'jim' in the array although there are several.

I tried the loop using an array I made myself and it worked fine, ie:

```
arr = ['jim', 'bob', 'arthur', 'jim', 'fred']
```

What is it about the array produced by string.match that I am not understanding? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should probably post more of the code involved, including the regular expression and the string you're testing with.

Comment: are you sure of the array content? have you tried to print it?

Comment: If your string doesn't match the actual regexp it returns `null` not an array.

Comment: The regex is /(?:^| )([a-zäöüß]+)(?= [A-Z])/g. It returns an array of words which occur before words starting with capitals. And it works in so much as it produces an array which can be seen via alert or console.log. I just can't manipulate it with .splice etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `|` metacharacter in the RegExp to produce an array such as this:

```
['jim', 'bob', 'arthur', 'jim', 'fred']
```

For example:

```
var arr = string.match(/jim|bob|arthur|fred/g);
```

And duplicates can be removed with the RegExp `/(\w+)(.*)+\1/,"$1$2"` as such:

```
/*Replace a word with a dupe with the original plus whatever words come in between*/
var arr = String(string.match(/jim|bob|arthur|fred/g)).replace(/(\w+)(.*)+\1/,"$1$2");

/*Remove the hanging comma*/
arr = arr.replace(/,$/,"");
```

Given input such as:

```
var string = "jim and bob and arthur and fred each have a brother named jim";
```

Works for the problem in question.

The replacer function can also do the same in case the RegExp is not flexible:

```
function myReplacer(substring, offset, fullstring) {

  var names = {'jim':"", 'bob':"", 'arthur':"", 'fred':""};

  if (substring in names)
    {
    return substring;
    }
}

var arr = string.replace(/\w+/g, myReplacer).replace("undefined","","g").replace(/\s+/g," ").replace(/(\w+)(.*)+\1/,"$1$2");
```

**References**

- [String.prototype.replace](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es5#sec-15.5.4.11)